# Is there a way to diagnose "whole system freezes" on Windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, driver, windbg, freeze

I'm developing a software driver for Windows (it's proprietary, so I cannot share the code, unfortunately). From time to time it makes the whole machine completely freeze permanently. I mean a "system-wide" freeze: the mouse cursor locks up, the keyboard LEDs do not respond to Num Lock presses, etc.

My question is rather simple: are there any productive ways to diagnose/debug problems like this?

Note how I mentioned "productive", so of course, I'm not considering "printf debugging" and other similar techniques.

The freeze is permanent and as such can only be "resolved" via performing a "hard shutdown" by holding down the power button for a few seconds. So far I have tried two approaches:

1. There is a registry option called [CrashOnCtrlScroll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard) which lets you manually initiate a BSOD (and therefore creation of a kernel-mode minidump) by pressing a key combination on your keyboard
2. Attaching with windbg from another machine and performing kernel debugging via the network

The first one simply does not work, nothing happens when the key combination is pressed (it does work in non-freeze scenarios, I tried it out). The second one with windbg also fails, because even though kernel debugging is started successfully (I can break in etc.) when the freeze happens, the target machine stops responding to commands.

(Rhetorical question: as far as I know, Microsoft collects kernel dumps automatically. How does MS get notified about system freezes in the general case, if dump creation is impossible in these scenarios? )

Comment: for 1.) The CrashOnCtrlScroll probably needs a PS/2 keyboard. USB won't work. For 3.) since it does not crash, MS will not get a dump of that. For 2.) I think it's an interesting question, but obviously people want you to ask it on SuperUser instead.

Comment: Microsoft provided [here some docs about debugging of hang](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-a-stalled-system)

Comment: @ThomasWeller: You are mistaken. In fact, CrashOnCtrlScroll indeed supports USB keyboards. [(Source.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard)

Comment: Dear OP, please see my post: ["What to do when CrashOnCtrlScroll doesn't seem to work"](https://superuser.com/questions/1606956/what-to-do-when-crashonctrlscroll-doesnt-seem-to-work).